# Writing CSV file while looping through web pages

Tags: python, loops, csv

This is a follow-up question to my earlier question on looping through multiple web pages. I am new to programming... so I appreciate your patience and very explicit explanations!

I have programmed a loop through many web pages. On each page, I want to scrape data, save it to a variable or a csv file (whichever is easier/more stable), then click on the "next" button, scrape data on the second page and append it to the variable or csv file, etc.

Specifically, my code looks like this:

```
url="http://www.url.com"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
(driver.page_source).encode('utf-8')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

while True:
    # some code to grab the data
    job_tag={'class': re.compile("job_title")}
    all_jobs=soup.findAll(attrs=job_tag)
    jobs=[]
    for text in (all_jobs):
     t=str(''.join(text.findAll(text=True)).strip()) 
     jobs.append(t)

    writer=csv.writer(open('test.csv','a', newline=''))
    writer.writerows(jobs)

    # click next link
   try:
       element=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='reviews']/a/span[starts-with(.,'Next')]")))
       element.click()
   except TimeoutException:
        break
```

It runs without error, but 
1) the file collects the data of the first page over and over again, but not the data of the subsequent pages, even though the loop performs correctly (ultimately, I do not really mind duplicate entries, but I do want data from all pages). 
I am suspecting that I need to "redefine" the soup for each new page, I am looking into how to make bs4 access those urls.

2) the last page has no "next" button, so the code does not append last page's data (I get that error when I use 'w' instead of 'a' in the csv line, with the data of the second-to-last page writing into the csv file).

Also, although it is a minor issue, the data gets written one letter per cell in the csv, even though when I run that portion in Python with bs4, the data is correctly formatted. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: How are `jobs` and `all_jobs` defined?  You probably need to reset the `jobs` variable each iteration to prevent repeating the existing lines.

Comment: @augurar I edited the post to reflect how they are defined. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am suspecting that I need to "redefine" the soup for each new page

Indeed, you should. You see, your `while` loop runs with `soup` always referring to the same old object you made before entering that `while` loop. You should rebind `soup` to a new `BeautifulSoup` instance, which is most likely the URL you find behind the `anchor` (tag `a`) which you've located in those last lines:

```
element=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='reviews']/a/span[starts-with(.,'Next')]")))
```

You could access it with just your `soup` (note that I haven't tested this for correctness: without the actual source of the page, I'm guessing):

```
next_link = soup.find(id='reviews').a.get('href')
```

And then, at the end of your `while` loop, you would rebind `soup`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(next_link.read()))
```

You should still add a `try - except` clause to capture the error it'll generate on the last page when it cannot find the last "Next" link and then break out of the loop.

Note that `selenium` is most likely not necessary for your use-case, `bs4` would be sufficient (but either would work).

> Also, although it is a minor issue, the data gets written one letter per cell in the csv, even though when I run that portion in Python with bs4, the data is correctly formatted. What am I missing?

The `writer` instance you've created expects an iterable for its `writerows` method. You are passing it a single string (which might have kommas in them, but that's not what `csv.writer`  will look at: it will add kommas (or whichever delimiter you specified in its construction) between every 2 items of the iterable). A Python string is iterable (per character), so `writer.writerows("some_string")` doesn't result in an error. But you most likely wanted this:

```
for text in (all_jobs):
    t = [x.strip() for x in text.find_all(text=True)]
    jobs.append(t)
```

As a follow-up on the comments:
You'll want to update the `soup` based on the new url, which you retrieve from the `1, 2, 3 Next >>` (it's in a `div` container with a specific `id`, so easy to extract with just `BeautifulSoup`). The code below is a fairly basic example that shows how this is done. Extracting the things you find relevant is done by your own scraping code, which you'll have to add as indicated in the example.

```
#Python3.x
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.indeed.com/cmp/Wesley-Medical-Center/reviews'
base_url_parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
while True:
    raw_html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html)
    # scrape the page for the desired info 
    # ...

    last_link = soup.find('div', id='company_reviews_pagination').find_all('a')[-1]
    if last_link.text.startswith('Next'):
        next_url_parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(last_link['href'])
        url = urllib.parse.urlunparse((base_url_parts.scheme, base_url_parts.netloc,
            next_url_parts.path, next_url_parts.params, next_url_parts.query,
            next_url_parts.fragment))
        print(url)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and let you know if that works (and accept your answer soon). Sorry for the delay - have been traveling.

Comment: Ok, I may be obtuse, but even if I try re-initiating the soup variable after clicking on each new page, the code does not work. Here is the page(s) I wish to scrape: http://www.indeed.com/cmp/Wesley-Medical-Center/reviews (this is the initial page; the program clicks on "next" until it reaches the last page).
Can anyone help? TIA!

Comment: @anne_t, now that I see the URL, do yo want to scrape the links hidden behind "1, 2, 3, Next" or do you want to "Review this company". My guess is the former, in which case you would be interested in `soup.find('div', id='company_reviews_pagination').find_all('a')[-1]['href']` rather than the `element=wait.until(...` written above. Beware though: that will return a relative hyperreference: you'll still need to add the scheme and the netlocation (being `http://www.indeed.com`).

Comment: Thanks! 
Just to make sure: I want to scrape the text of the three pages: the initial one (http://www.indeed.com/cmp/Wesley-Medical-Center/reviews), the text of the second one, and so on. 
I get the program to click on the "next" allright, but it is the re-initialization of the soup (and the appending of the scraping results to a csv file) that causes me trouble.

Comment: @anne_t I've added a more elaborate example that shows how to update the `soup`.  Appending the scraping results to a csv file is fairly well-documented, I think you'll manage. Good luck!